# Passing Controller's $scope variable to nested directive's controller

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-controller

I'm having trouble passing a scope object from one controller to a nested directive's controller.
I have a directive (child) within another directive (parent), the parent directive and its controller look like this:

```
myApp.directive('parent', function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope:false,
        controller: 'parentController',
        templateUrl : '/templates/parent.html',
    };
});

myApp.controller('parentController', ['$scope',
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.monitors=[monitor1,monitor2,monitor3]; //in reality these are JSON objects
}
```

My 'parent.html' template looks like this:

```
<div>
    <!-- Other things go here -->
    <div ng-repeat='monitor in monitors'>
        <child monitorData='monitor'></child>
    </div>
</div>
```

The child directive and its controller look like this:

```
myApp.directive('child', function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope:{
            monitorData:'=',
        },
        bindToController:true,
        controller: 'childController',
        templateUrl : '/templates/child.html',
    };
});

myApp.controller('childController', ['$scope', function ChildController($scope) {
    var vm=this;

    console.log('instantiated childController');
    console.log(vm);
}]);
```

The console output is this:

```
instantiated childController
ChildController
    monitorData : undefined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a data in monitor data ? 
Try use monitor-Data insted of monitorData in place when you are passing parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use monitor-Data insted of monitorData.

```
<div>
<!-- Other things go here -->
<div ng-repeat='monitor in monitors'>
    <child monitor-Data='monitor'></child>
</div>
```

> From angular documentacion: Note: These =attr attributes in the scope
>   option of directives are normalized just like directive names. To bind
>   to the attribute in < div bind-to-this="thing">, you'd specify a
>   binding of =bindToThis.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: That was it.. Thank you @Ridikk12

Comment: Now I get the following:
MonitorController
     monitor-data:Object
Just one more thing,  how do I access this monitor-data from within chilldController?
vm.monitor-data is undefined :S

Comment: $scope.monitorData

Comment: Undefined as well

Comment: got it... didn't use bindToController nor controllerAs anymore.
All this had been implemented because I couldn't get monitorData within the controller but by fixing the name to monitor-data, the two way binding was done succesfully